# Error go test -v on https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode

Tags: go, webhooks, linode, cert-manager

I completely make a config and create a token on linode
but i got this error when try to test my fetch-test-binaries.sh

this is the message

```
go test -v
# github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode [github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode.test]
./main_test.go:20:7: undefined: dns.SetBinariesPath
./main_test.go:20:23: undefined: kubeBuilderBinPath
FAIL    github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode [build failed]
make: *** [Makefile:15: verify] Error 2
```

can someone help me to resolve please ?

The error on file
main_test.go line 7 & 23 Link FIle : https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode/blob/master/main_test.go

and makefile line 15 Link File : https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode/blob/master/Makefile

The Repository Link : https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode

I have tried to resolve with downgrade or upgrade my Go Version and searching but i found nothing,

I tried to just go test -v(not doing anything, just clone & go test) but i got same error

Please Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetBinariesPath` was removed from `cert-manager` in commit [cd92bf321fe14f857f34763583071e068f6c96b3](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/commit/cd92bf321fe14f857f34763583071e068f6c96b3#diff-c3d4312f6a40ccfbc10c5a08afed1b11c3ac1b5f5bf12150154274255369cc09L162)

`github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode` was updated to a newer version of `cert-manager` in commit [7131f7755b1278e48341f0d71fabac5b56b964fb](https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode/commit/7131f7755b1278e48341f0d71fabac5b56b964fb) - and it looks like that moved to a version of `cert-manager` which includes the removal of `SetBinariesPath`. The var declaration for `kubeBuilderBinPath` was correctly stripped away, but the call to `dns.SetBinariesPath` and a reference to the now removed `kubeBuilderBinPath` still remain.

So, essentially the code in `main_test.go` is invalid - at minimum [line 20](https://github.com/slicen/cert-manager-webhook-linode/blob/cd89b19a82618395c6f0bd488ef7b220e2098022/main_test.go#L20) should be removed.

Comment: thats right sir, after i remove the line number 20, the error has been gone, thankyou so much